# Discord.py on_ready for member in ctx.guild.members:

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Мой код должен получать айди  всех людей серверах с ботом
я делал такой код с @client.command, но мне надо с @client.event on_ready():

```
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    for member in ctx.guild.members:
      idas = print(member.id)
```

ошибка:

```
Ignoring exception in on_ready
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Никитос\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Никитос\Desktop\Nukebot.py", line 25, in on_ready
    for member in guild.members:
NameError: name 'guild' is not defined
```

Comment: Когда вы реализуете функционал через `client.command`, бот при получении команды точно знает, с какого сервера пришла команда. При реализации же с `on_ready` у бота нет контекста (`ctx`), из которого он должен понимать, о каком именно сервере идёт речь (бот - тоже пользователь Discord, и он тоже может быть одновременно на нескольких серверах). Либо в цикле перебирать все сервера, на которых есть этот бот, либо заранее дать боту ID сервера и получать пользователей с какого-то заранее известного сервера.

Comment: как сделать этот цикл перебор серверов?

Answer (score 1):

```
from discord.ext.commands import Bot

client = Bot(command_prefix='.')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    # Перебираем все сервера в которых находится бот
    for guild in client.guilds:
        for member in guild.members:
            id = member.id
            print(str(id))
```